# How do I generate a <button> tag with an <i> inside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to produce this HTML:

```
<a class="action-btn btn-delete" href="/product/9">
  <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> 
</a>
```

But I read that I need to use the `button_to` helper method, rather than `link_to`.

So I tried this:

```
<%= button_to product, method: :delete, class: "action-btn btn-delete" do %>
  <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>
<% end %>
```

But that doesn't work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to product, :method => "DELETE", :class => "action-btn btn-delete" do %>
  <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you can't use `[link_to][1]`

```
        <%= link_to product, class: "action-btn btn-delete" do %>             
          <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try, it may work,

```
<%= link_to product, method: :delete, class: "action-btn btn-delete" do %>
  <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Delete
<% end %>
```